# How to insert a table in an SMTP email? And the list includes a double

Tags: c#, list, smtp

The following code does not put everything in an email.  The only result is the word test.  When I run all code, there is data from the database.  What am I missing to get the data to populate in the email table?

```
performanceCompare += "<table>";

//Compares last hour today......need to compare to another day results
        var performDate = ErrDb.PerformanceDatas.Where(d => d.loggedAt > hourlyBegin && d.loggedAt < hourlyEnd).ToList();
        var performanceDataOneDay = ErrDb.PerformanceDatas.Where(o => o.loggedAt > dayBegin && o.loggedAt < dayEnd).ToList();

        performanceCompare += "<tr>";
        performanceCompare += "<td><b>test</b></td>";
        performanceCompare += "</tr>";

        var avgTimeList = new List<AvgTime>();
        var specialIDS = performDate.Select(x => new {x.sitename, x.functionName }) .Distinct();

        foreach (var key in specialIDS)
        {
            var funComapre = performDate.Where(g => g.functionName == key.functionName && g.sitename == key.sitename);

            AvgTime avgTime = new AvgTime();
            avgTime.siteName = "<tr>" + key.sitename + "</tr>";
            avgTime.functionName = "<td>" + funComapre.Select(x => x.functionName).First() + "</td>";
            avgTime.avgFunctTime = "<td>" + (funComapre.Select(x => x.functionTime).Average()) + "</td>";//needs to be a string, not a double
            avgTimeList.Add(avgTime);


            var anotherFunComapre = performanceDataOneDay.Where(g => g.functionName == key.functionName && g.sitename == key.sitename);

            if (anotherFunComapre != null)
            {
                AvgTime anotherAvgTime = new AvgTime();
                avgTime.siteName = "<tr>" + key.sitename + "</tr>";
                avgTime.functionName = "<td>" + funComapre.Select(x => x.functionName).First() + "</td>";
                anotherAvgTime.avgFunctTime = funComapre.Select(x => x.functionTime).Average();
                avgTimeList.Add(anotherAvgTime);

            }

        }

        performanceCompare += "</table>";
```

Comment: Well you append nothing to `performanceCompare` either within the loop or after the loop, so if you then use it it only contains the single TD cell.

Comment: @AlexK. If I structure this:

foreach()
{
performanceCompare += "<>";
}

What do I do about the x.functionTime?  I get errors when I use "<td>" tags.